# Spring property placeholder decrypt resolved property

Tags: java, spring

I'm looking to see if there is a way that I can intercept the property placeholder mechanism such that if I have a resolved property value that is marked in some way as encrypted, I can decrypt and use the result as the resolved value.

Jasypt has support for something like this but actually decrypts all property values before attempting to decorate beans.

Any thoughts or ideas?

I have a decryption mechanism of my own making and mark the value strings as encrypted with {AES} as a prefix on the encoded value.

*EDIT* So as I said above about the Jasypt implementation, intercepting in the same fashion would get me the correct decryption, which I have working. My concern is - how long are the collection of properties kept in memory or do they fade off after the end of the placeholder configurer usage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could extend `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and override the `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.convertPropertyValue(String)` method decrypting it if it starts with `"{EAS}"`.  Something like the following class could be used as `PropertyPlaceHolder`:

```
package foo.bar;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;

public class EncryptationAwarePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer{

@Override
protected String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue) {
    if (originalValue.startsWith("{AES}")) {
        return decrypt(originalValue.substring(5));
    }
    return originalValue;
}

private String decrypt(String value) {
    return value.toLowerCase(); // here your decryption logic
}
```

}

Your context would have `PropertyPlaceholder` declared as:

```
<bean class="foo.bar.EncryptationAwarePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>my.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You would use the property as easy as:

```
@Value("${encryptedMyProtectedValue}")
private String decryptedValue;
```

EDIT: `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory)` will basically load properties (to a local Properties object), convert and process them. The processing occurs by invoking `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory, Properties)`. Using `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` the `Properties` object will not be hold in memory after beans processing. It will basically be used just to set properties of beans in your context and will be disposed.

Comment: Giving you a +1 on this as I've already gotten through that part :-). I'm editing my question with concerns