# Manipulation of Spring Bean property

Tags: spring, properties, jasypt

I want to change a property of a bean. I want to change it only once for performance (better when reading from XML), not in every bean instance instantiation. What is the best way to do it in Spring?

For elaborating and giving a concrete example:

Below is the datasource bean declaration in databaseContext.xml.
I want to decrypt ${jdbc.password} whose value is ENC(....) with JASYPT.
I could not do it with Jaspt Spring integration since Jaspt not compliant yet with Spring5 and  not with Jasypt Hibernate integration since using a different datasource other than Hibernate.

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
        <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 from dual" />
        <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${jdbc.user}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me a lot:
[Spring property placeholder decrypt resolved property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077206/spring-property-placeholder-decrypt-resolved-property)

Just want to add some small correction and extra notes about some findings:

In the link above it is written "location", but it must be "locations" as written below, where it resides at applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="com.dummy.util.EncryptationAwarePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:database.properties</value>
            <value>classpath*:hibernate.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

"PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" is deprecated. But it still works. If you try to use the newly proposed class "PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer", it has a bug that it does not call "convertPropertyValue" method as noted here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13568.  A workaround noted by the way there.

```
public class EncryptationAwarePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue) {

        if (originalValue != null && originalValue.startsWith("ENC(")) {
            return decrypt(originalValue);
        }
        return originalValue;
    }

    .
    .
}
```